# Proving Band Limited implies Unbounded Support without complex analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I am looking for a proof of the fact that a Band Limited signal has unbounded support in the time domain without invoking properties of holomorphic functions/complex analysis.

Does one exist?

Comment: The Fourier transform of a bounded function with compact support is analytic (and entire). In particular if it vanishes on an interval of the real line then it vanishes everywhere.

Comment: You can invoke properties of a Laurent series instead, which is the underlying principle for the complex analysis proof. Once you factor out a finite order zero, the series cannot vanish in a neighborhood of the point.